# Why is 8x8 matrix pins do not correspond to rows and columns order?

Tags: led

It would be easier to program led matrix if 1-8 pins corresponded to 1-8 rows and 9-16 pins corresponded to 1-8 columns.
Instead there is the following arrangement:
[image: 8x8 led matrix pins to rows/columns arrangement]

Why is it made like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's probably easier to manufacture, other than that, I don't see why.
If this is a serious issue, you can contact your manufacturer, since he is most likely to know why.

You can:

1. Work around the issue, by wiring pin 1 to input 9, pin 2 to input 14 etc.
2. Make a software solution like:

   #define ROW1 9

   #define ROW2 14
3. Buy an LED-matrix that has the pins in the correct order (check the datasheet before purchase).